# GLES20 parse obj file and vertex, texture indices

Tags: android, opengl-es

I'm new in OpenGL-ES 2.0 and try to parse .obj file and draw on Android.

And I've succeed draw a simple cube with parsed data from .obj file

```
the 'v' (vertex coords)
and the first values of 'f' line (v index)
```

but the next step, I need to draw 'Texture' with .obj data, I found there is 'Texture Index' and I've no idea how can I use this 'Texture Index' with my codes

```
GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(mPositionHandle, 3, GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false, VSTRIDE, vertexCoords);
GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(mPositionHandle);

GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(maTextureHandle, 2, GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false, TSTRIDE, textureCoords);
GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(maTextureHandle);

...

GLES20.glDrawElements(GLES20.GL_TRIANGLES, indexLength, GLES20.GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, vertexIndices);
```

I think, only 'Vertex indices' parameter can use on glDrawElements API.
How can I use glDrawElements with 'Vertex Indices' and 'Texture Indices'?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can´t use texture indices with GLES20.glDrawElements.

GLES20.glDrawElements can't draw elements with multiple textures, it will allways use the "current texture"

You set the Current texture binding a previosusly created texture. 
`GLES20.glBindTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureID); //Next call of glDrawElements will use this texture`

It's a good idea to order vertices by the texture id and execute one GLES20.glDrawElements call for each texture id

Comment: Thanks for your relpy julito. so should I call glDrawElement multiple times?

Comment: OpenGL ES support multiple textures in one draw call just fine - you just have to bind them to different texture units. Do *not* draw multiple times with one texture per layer, that will be horribly horribly expensive on mobile GPUs where geometry is a significant bandwidth cost.

Comment: The different texture units are used for multitexturing (mixing various textures in the same surface). But he is just asking about drawing a mesh with multiple textures. And for that the only way is using multiple calls to the drawing function.

Comment: Wavefront .obj files only support referencing a single texture so you only need one draw, and Wavefront .mtl files are using multitexturing so you only need one draw. Texture indices in the question are actually texture coordinates; see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wavefront_.obj_file#Vertex_Texture_Coordinate_Indices.